# Can I apply the C11 `_Atomic` keyword to enum types?

Tags: c, enums, c11, stdatomic

If I have a type

```
enum foo {
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ,
};
```

can I then declare an atomic version of that type like

```
_Atomic(enum foo);
```

or do I have to use e.g. `atomic_int` and cast the result of `atomic_load()`?

The following program compiles without warnings:

```
    #include <stdatomic.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    enum foo {FOO, BAR, BAZ};

    int main(void) {
        _Atomic(enum foo) foo_a;
        atomic_store(&foo_a, BAR);
        enum foo val = atomic_load(&foo_a);
        printf("%u\n", val);
        return 0;
    }
```

but so does:

```
    #include <stdatomic.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    enum foo {FOO, BAR, BAZ};

    int main(void) {
        enum foo foo; // <---- non atomic
        atomic_store(&foo, BAR);
        enum foo val = atomic_load(&foo);
        printf("%u\n", val);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: According to http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.4p3 there is no prevention to use `_Atomic` with `enum`.

Comment: Side-note: If all you're doing is `atomic_store` and `atomic_load`, you can just declare `_Atomic(enum foo) foo_a;` and then use normal reads/assignment; IIRC, `_Atomic` qualified types perform sequentially consistent reads/writes (matching plain `atomic_load`/`atomic_store`, which are also sequentially consistent) automatically. If declared `_Atomic`, `foo = BAR;` and `enum foo val = foo;` will still be atomic operations. I'm not 100% sure on this (inc/dec/compound assignment are all definitely sequentially consistent; it's possible less strict semantics are used for plain read/write).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: AFAIK, you always need to use `atomic_store_explicit(..., memory_order_release)` any time you want ordering weaker than seq_cst.  There's no way to make `++` or `=` default to acq/rel or relaxed instead of seq_cst.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yeah, that's what I thought. Didn't find that guarantee for plain loads and stores on first check, just for read-modify-write operations, but I wouldn't be surprised if they erred on the side of caution even for the simplest operations.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: It's possible that gcc / clang just chose that behaviour when they didn't have to; I didn't check the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all data types can be atomic, and there is no need to use the atomic generic functions for these. All operations with such an object is then atomic.

For your second example it is weird that you compiler does not issue a warning. Using a non-atomic for an atomic operation is a constraint violation, so the compiler should give you a diagnostic.

Comment: At a guess on the second example, the machine they're compiling on doesn't put any special requirements on `_Atomic` types that the non-`_Atomic` type doesn't already satisfy (size is unchanged, alignment is already correct), and the compiler is just being lazy and ignoring the spec violation.

Comment: It makes sense that parameters should be _Atomic, but in C17 7.17.7.1 it shows the format as `void atomic_store(volatile A *object, C desired);`. Why are these parameters not `_Atomic` qualified? Where exactly is the constraint violation you speak of?

Comment: @Lundin AFAIR in this clause `A` always refers to an atomic type.

Comment: Ok but I still don't get how it can be a constraint violation to pass `pointer-to-type` to a function expecting `qualified-pointer-to-type`. The `atomic_type` types don't seem to be distinct types, but typedefs of `_Atomic type`.

Comment: Because `_Atomic` only looks like a qualifier and isn't really one. The rule is *The phrase "qualified or unqualified type", without specific
mention of atomic, does not include the atomic types.* So pointers to types with and without atomic qualification are not compatible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is legal.  BTW, you don't actually need the parens, `_Atomic enum foo foo;` is equivalent.

`_Atomic` works like other type qualifiers, like `const` and `volatile`.

---

```
enum foo foo;
atomic_store(&foo, BAR);
```

**is an error with clang**.  `error: address argument to atomic operation must be a pointer to _Atomic type ('enum foo *' invalid)`.  (From [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdatomic.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aenum+foo+%7B%0A++++FOO,%0A++++BAR,%0A++++BAZ,%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main(void)+%7B%0A%0A++++//+_Atomic%0A++++enum+foo+foo%3B%0A++++atomic_store(%26foo,+BAR)%3B%0A%0A++++enum+foo+val+%3D+atomic_load(%26foo)%3B%0A%0A++++printf(%22%25u%5Cn%22,+val)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.28485199150843,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.978993011799986,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.736154996691596,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+7.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:31.736154996691596,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).

---

It's just a quirk of GCC's implementation that it compiles without even a warning, even at `-Wall`.  That should probably be changed...

[GCC's atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) like `void __atomic_store_n (type *ptr, type val, int memorder)` take a pointer to a plain type, without requiring `_Atomic`.

C++11 `<atomic>` uses these builtins.  Similarly, GCC's C11 `stdatomic.h` uses

```
#define atomic_store_explicit(PTR, VAL, MO)                             \
  __extension__                                                         \
  ({                                                                    \
    __auto_type __atomic_store_ptr = (PTR);                             \
    __typeof__ (*__atomic_store_ptr) __atomic_store_tmp = (VAL);        \
    __atomic_store (__atomic_store_ptr, &__atomic_store_tmp, (MO));     \
  })

#define atomic_store(PTR, VAL)                          \
  atomic_store_explicit (PTR, VAL, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)
```

(The `__extension__` is for the GNU C statement-expression, where `x = {foo; bar;}` takes the value of `bar`.)

So none of this actually requires that the pointer type has `_Atomic`.